# Precise scheduling of scripts in powershell

Tags: powershell, scheduling

I have number of monitoring functions that I want to execute with dynamic frequencies, depending on project. The range of frequencies are from once every second, to once a day. TaskScheduler or ScheduledJob are not precise enough for this purpose.

Is any function scheduler such as this available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created script for this purpose that you can find on [github](https://github.com/majkinetor/flea)

Answer (score 0):

Spinning up a powershell instance is not a trivial event.  If you're wanting monitoring on a frequency less than a few minutes you'll be much better off to write a script that stays resident and runs in an endless process-sleep-process loop.

Comment: Yes, thats why I wonder is anybody wrote such script already. I don't want to reinvent things.

Comment: I've written a few of them.  It's a pretty trivial matter to wrap it in a while ($true){} loop, with a start-sleep at the end.

Comment: Its not that trivial if you want to be precise with time (i.e. no latency given the frequency of execution). Sleeping is also problematic as job events are not received during it.

Comment: I do not know how to attain "no latency".  It's starting to sound like what you want is timer event triggered execution, not scheduling.

Comment: I need both scheduling and timer events as some events are run couple of times per day, and some every few seconds. I typically have around 20 functions to run per project. So I specify frequency for some functions, i.e. every 10s, and specific time for others (start time and different frequency). The later can be setup via TaskScheduler but I don't want to separate those two kind of functions. Perhaps I should present my current script ?

Comment: I think your question is too broad/vague. You need to narrow it down to a specific scenario, or specific sets of criteria.

Comment: I don't understand what combination you can't use Task Scheduler for? You can set up several triggers to handle multiple types of cases, for ex. triggering every day, and then repeating the task every second for 15 minutes. Reiterating @mjolinor's last comment, Can you please edit your post to outline one specific example of a sequence of events that you want to accomplish.

Comment: You may want to take a look at Scheduled Jobs: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/03/05/powershell-jobs-week-scheduled-jobs.aspx

Comment: @HAL9256, Task Scheduler doesn't allow repeating in seconds, only minutes.

Comment: I see. You are right, I didn't realize that the Task Scheduler could only repeat in minutes and not seconds. I guess your options are really to either code something yourself using timer events (See: http://jrich523.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/creating-a-timer-event-in-powershell/), or to use a 3rd party task scheduler. For ex. You could look at something like Visualcron (https://www.visualcron.com) it looks like it may give you a whole lot more flexibility and scheduling options that may fit your needs.

Comment: @HAL9256, yes, I am here precisely to find out is there any kind of 3thd party *powershell* scheduler available, but it seems there isn't any. I almost finished my own so that solves it. I don't want to introduce 3thd party non-powershell solution such as visualcron, especially if it comes with 'visual' attribute.

Comment: I created script for this purpose that you can find on github. See my answer bellow.